# Copy items from JList to JTable

Tags: swing, jtable, jframe, jbutton, jlist

I have a simple JFrame with a JList, a JTable and two JButton as below

[image]

I would like to copy selected item(s) from the List to Table with the "Add" button, and remove  item(s) in Table (when added) by the "Remove" button.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can't find examples to follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a listener to the buttons that gets the selected item from the list and modifies the table accordingly.  Here is some code to get you started:

```
        final JButton add = new JButton();
    final JButton remove = new JButton();
    final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    final JList list = new JList();

    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object selectedPlanet = list.getSelectedValue();
            tableModel.addRow(new Object[] { selectedPlanet });
        }
    });
    remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object selectedPlanet = list.getSelectedValue();
            int columnContainingPlanets = 0;
            for (int index = columnContainingPlanets; index < tableModel.getRowCount(); index ++)
                if (tableModel.getValueAt(index, columnContainingPlanets).equals(selectedPlanet)) {
                    tableModel.removeRow(index);
                    break;
                }
        }
    });
```